# the order within group apply function

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Having the code (below) I am trying to figure will particular group order *always* remain the same as in original dataframe.

It looks like the order within the group preserved for my little example, but what if I have dataframe with ~1 mln records? Will pandas provide such guarantee and I should worry about that by myself?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(index = xrange(N))
df['A'] = map(lambda x: int(x) / 5, np.random.randn(N) * 10.0)
df['B'] = map(lambda x: int(x) / 5, np.random.randn(N) * 10.0)
df['v'] = np.random.randn(N)

def show_x(x):
    print x
    print "----------------"
df.groupby('A').apply(show_x)
print "==============="
print df
```

Output:

```
   A  B         v
6 -4 -1 -2.047354

[1 rows x 3 columns]
----------------
   A  B         v
6 -4 -1 -2.047354

[1 rows x 3 columns]
----------------
   A  B         v
8 -3  0 -1.190831

[1 rows x 3 columns]
----------------
   A  B         v
0 -1 -1  0.456397
9 -1 -2 -1.329169

[2 rows x 3 columns]
----------------
   A  B         v
1  0  0  0.663928
2  0  2  0.626204
7  0 -3 -0.539166

[3 rows x 3 columns]
----------------
   A  B         v
4  2  2 -1.115721
5  2  1 -1.905266

[2 rows x 3 columns]
----------------
   A  B         v
3  4 -1  0.751016

[1 rows x 3 columns]
----------------
===============
   A  B         v
0 -1 -1  0.456397
1  0  0  0.663928
2  0  2  0.626204
3  4 -1  0.751016
4  2  2 -1.115721
5  2  1 -1.905266
6 -4 -1 -2.047354
7  0 -3 -0.539166
8 -3  0 -1.190831
9 -1 -2 -1.329169

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: order is preserved within a group and to the subframe that is passed to apply or a reduction function. you should show what you are doing and why this matters.

Comment: @Jeff it matters for apply functions like x - x.shift(1). If order is not preserved I may get wrong answer.

Comment: It IS preserved (see @Andy Hayden answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using apply not only is the order not guaranteed, but as you've found it can trigger the function for the same group a couple of times (to decide which "path" to take / what type of result to return). So if your function has side-effects don't do this!

I recommend simply iterating through the groupby object!

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  4
2  5  6

In [13]: g = df.groupby('A')

In [14]: for key, sub_df in g:
             print("key =", key)
             print(sub_df)
             print('')   # apply whatever function you want
key = 1
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  4

key = 5
   A  B
2  5  6
```

Note that this *is* ordered (the same as the levels) see `g.grouper._get_group_keys()`:

```
In [21]: g.grouper.levels
Out[21]: [Int64Index([1, 5], dtype='int64')]
```

*It's sorted by default (there's a sort kwarg when doing the groupby), through it's not clear what this actually means if it's not a numeric dtype.*

Comment: thanks for answer but my question is different: I am interested about order within the group. I.e. dataframe which is arg of function being applied (show_x in my example): will the order of rows be always the same as in original dataframe (or it may not be the case)

Comment: to be perfectly clear: can pandas guarantee that sub_df and df  will *always* have the same order of common rows?